# MySQL datatime versus timestamp with regards to how time is recorded/displayed

Tags: mysql, heroku, timestamp

I just noticed this in a test run

```
    mysql> select * from enumdecoder;
+----+---------------------+---------------------+------+--------------------+-------+-------+------+----------+

| ID | CreateStamp         | ModStamp            | Flag | className          | value | label | abv  | sequence |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+------+--------------------+-------+-------+------+----------+
|  1 | 2015-04-22 03:11:17 | 2015-04-22 15:11:18 |    0 | TestElementFactory | ONE   | NULL  | One  |       10 |
|  2 | 2015-04-22 03:11:17 | 2015-04-22 15:11:18 |    0 | TestElementFactory | TWO   | NULL  | Two  |       20 |
|  3 | 2015-04-22 03:11:17 | 2015-04-22 15:11:18 |    0 | TestElementFactory | THREE | NULL  | Thre |       30 |
|  4 | 2015-04-22 03:11:18 | 2015-04-22 15:11:18 |    0 | NULL               | NULL  | NULL  | NULL |        0 |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+------+--------------------+-------+-------+------+----------+
```

The definition of the table is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE enumdecoder (
    ID bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    CreateStamp datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '2000-01-01 00:00:00',
    ModStamp timestamp,
    Flag bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    className char(254),
    value char(50),
    label char(50),
    abv char(5),
    sequence smallint(3) SIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);
```

In case you wondering why the default it's because I'm currently jumping through hoops to get Heroku to play nice with the play framework (something it claims to do out of the box) Heroku won't allow for either multiple columns to have a auto updating timestamp nor will they allow for triggers. I've re-written my core db library to accommodate them and that default will make anything that slips through the cracks stick out like a sore thumb.

Comment: Not being able to have more than one autuo-updating timestamp is not a Heroku problem, but rather MySQL behavior.  That being said, I don;t see what question you are actually asking here.  What problem are you having?

Comment: `DATETIME` items are always stored in local time. `TIMESTAMP` items, on the other hand, are stored in Z time. They're translated to Z time when being stored, and back to local time when being retrieved, based on the timezone setting of the client connection.  Keep an eye out for that.

Comment: @OllieJones -- I'm actually trying to figure out what Best Practice is for handling shall we say "globally aware timestamps" end to end... (but that is NOT this question).

Comment: @MikeBrant well it *is* a platform problem is that is the limits of the database offering...

Answer (score 0):

Ah - answered it while writing this question!

Had the following defined as a time source:

```
val sqlfmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
```

What I really needed was of course...

```
val sqlfmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
def now = new DateTime()
def sqlnow = sqlfmt.print(now)
```

Good think I noticed this in the afternoon!

Now I get the expected:

```
mysql> select * from enumdecoder;
+----+---------------------+---------------------+------+--------------------+-------+-------+------+----------+
| ID | CreateStamp         | ModStamp            | Flag | className          | value | label | abv  | sequence |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+------+--------------------+-------+-------+------+----------+
|  1 | 2015-04-22 15:18:40 | 2015-04-22 15:18:41 |    0 | TestElementFactory | ONE   | NULL  | One  |       10 |
|  2 | 2015-04-22 15:18:40 | 2015-04-22 15:18:41 |    0 | TestElementFactory | TWO   | NULL  | Two  |       20 |
|  3 | 2015-04-22 15:18:40 | 2015-04-22 15:18:41 |    0 | TestElementFactory | THREE | NULL  | Thre |       30 |
|  4 | 2015-04-22 15:18:41 | 2015-04-22 15:18:41 |    0 | NULL               | NULL  | NULL  | NULL |        0 |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+------+--------------------+-------+-------+------+----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Figured I'd post anyways in case you needed something to laugh at today :)

Comment: Lesson learned: Don't assume anything and test everything! For those of you still scratching your heads this is a little bit like Where's Waldo -- obvious once you see it. Look at the `CreateStamp` versus the `ModStamp` columns -- it should be impossible to have a `CreateStamp` ahead of the `ModStamp`! (Hmmm one more unit test coming up...)